# Javascript getmouse

Tags: javascript, hover, mousehover

I found a neat plugin named "isomer master". This allows you to make an isometric landscape using coordinates and colors. What im trying to do currently is make a placement grid in which you hover your mouse over an area to place a block. The syntax is as follows:

```
  var Shape = Isomer.Shape;
var Point = Isomer.Point;
var Color = Isomer.Color;
var red = new Color(160, 60, 50);
var blue = new Color(226, 99, 0);


iso.add(Shape.Prism(Point.ORIGIN, 3, 3, 1));
iso.add(Shape.Pyramid(Point(0, 2, 1)), red);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sort of slow today. Your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using incorrect syntax in getting the mouse's position.

Comment: What was the correct syntax? I don't see any mouse-related code in your question or answer, so I don't see the value this offers to future visitors.